# Who said this quote?

Tags: quotations

Does anyone know who said the following quote: “what is forbidden is forbidden, and what is permissible is not necessarily to be done.”

I think it may be from a modern rabbi but I don’t recall who said it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's attributed to the Alter Rebbe in Hayom Yom, [25 Adar II](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/6137/jewish/Hayom-Yom-25-Adar-II.htm):

> The chassid, R. Mordechai Horodoker, related: The first aphorism we
> heard from the Alter Rebbe when we arrived in Lyozna was: *What is
> forbidden is forbidden, and what is permitted is unnecessary.* For
> some three or four years we labored with this until we integrated this
> manner (of service) into the various aspects of our lives. Only then
> did we enter into *yechidus*, to ask for a path in *avoda*.

Comment: The Yiddish is even better

Comment: @Moishe What isn't?